# Errors from `node-gyp build`: invalid value 'gnu++1y' in '-std=gnu++1y'

Tags: c++, node.js, npm, node-gyp, node.js-addon

UPDATE. Output of `gcc -v` as requested:

```
→ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

---

I am trying to follow the [Node.js official addons example](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_hello_world)

The `node-gyp configure` step runs without errors.

However, the following `node-gyp build` step is failing:

```
→ node-gyp build
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.2
gyp info using node@10.16.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/addon/hello.o
error: invalid value 'gnu++1y' in '-std=gnu++1y'
make: *** [Release/obj.target/addon/hello.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/dmitrizaitsev/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:190:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 12.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/dmitrizaitsev/.npm-global/bin/node-gyp" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/dmitrizaitsev/test/addons/official
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

The first error message is

```
invalid value 'gnu++1y' in '-std=gnu++1y'
```

What does it mean and how can this error possibly be fixed?

Comment: your compiler probably doesn't support c++14

Comment: Please post the result of `gcc -v`

Comment: @AlanBirtles How can I find out about the `c++ 14` support? And how to fix it?

Comment: @user6556709 Please see the update at the top of the question, thanks.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev  The gcc 4.2.1 didn't even support C++11.

Comment: @user6556709 Is there any way I can install it? As part of clang? With MacPorts? I have a very limited experience with gcc.

Comment: The Xcode commandline tools should come with a much more modern version of Clang.

Comment: @Botje Thanks, I downloaded the latest Xcode CLT for my osx (10.8.5) and it amazingly fixed the problem, while the last line with version number disappeared from the `gcc -v` output, giving clang-503.0.40